# How to pass currentPage rom UIScrollView to newViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

For the life of me I can't seem to figure this out. I must be completely overthinking this...

I have a UIScrollView that will hold a between 1-3 UIImageView(w UIImage) inside my tableView.

TableViewCell:
I'm calling...

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentPage = (CGFloat(imageScrollView.contentOffset.x) / CGFloat(userImageView!.frame.size.width))
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

to find out what page the user is currently looking at. My question is how do I pass the currentPage number to my new ViewController?

TableViewController:

In my CellForRowAtIndex I'm calling to find out which button was clicked.

```
cell.tapToViewButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.tapToViewButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I'm using

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if (segue.identifier == "toViewImageVC"){
let viewImageVC: ViewImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewImageViewController
//passed [UIImage] correctly

//HOW TO PASS CURRENT PAGE????----

}
}
```

I've tried several things like using the UIScrollViewDelegate in my TableView, using creating a method in my tableViewCell that returns an Int() which is my current page but I can't access it through tableView cause that only loads the cell info.

This seems simple but for some reason I can't wrap my head around this!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewImageViewController add a page parameter, like:

```
var pageNumber = 0
```

Then in prepareForSegue call:

```
viewImageVC.pageNumber = pageControl.currentPage
```

Comment: How do I get the pageControl.currentPage number? I'm using that scroll function in my UITableViewCell. the Prepare for segue is in my tableViewController.